# Status Code: 401 1001: Invalid access token Check the value of the Authorization HTTP request header

Tags: php

I have started making new development with eBay apis.

I am using the following example..
https://github.com/davidtsadler/ebay-sdk-examples/

after I have done all the api settings. 
https://github.com/davidtsadler/ebay-sdk-examples/blob/master/configuration.php.example

I am getting that error message

> " Status Code: 401 1001: Invalid access token Invalid access token.
>   Check the value of the Authorization HTTP request header. " in the
>   "/account/01-retrieve-all-policies.php"

How can I solve that. could you help me.

Comment: @david-t-sadler,

Comment: You should add your code